# Find isDirty() for children elements

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails3, beforeupdate, grails3.2.0

I'm using Grails 3.2:

```
class Training{
    boolean clientChanged = false
    static transients = ['clientChanged']

    static hasMany = [clients:User]
    //...

    def beforeUpdate(){
        clientChanged = this.isDirty('clients')
    }

    def afterUpdate(){
        if(clientChanged && section.clients)
            numberOfAbsentClients = section.clients.size() - (clients.size()?:0)
    }
}
```

`isDirty()` is not working for hasMany associations. how can I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections are handled slightly differently. Depending on whether you are using Hibernate or one of the other implementations of GORM you need to check if the collection is a `org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentCollection` (for Hibernate) or a `org.grails.datastore.mapping.collection.PersistentCollection` (for MongoDB/Neo4j/etc)

The `PersistentCollection` interface has a `isDirty()` method that you can use to check if the association was changed. So something like:

```
 if(clients instanceof PersistentCollection && clients.isDirty()) { 
     ...
 }
```

Will do it.